# Can't start apache on port 80

Tags: apache-http-server

I installed apache under linux in the home directory.
Now, if I try to start apache it says:

> [Wed Feb 27 11:59:37 2013] [crit] (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to port 80

this is because I'm not root, so I just do

```
sudo ./apachectl start
```

but in this case the error is:

> [Wed Feb 27 12:01:48 2013] [alert] (22)Invalid argument: initgroups: unable to set groups for User nobody and Group 4294967295

because of group error.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Is that error a literal quote? Because that looks a bit odd for a group name or GID....

Comment: The error is strange but might be miss leading somehow... Make sure there nothing running on 80. Try `netstat -aonp | grep :80 | grep LISTEN`.